# How to use elements in a nested list in pandas df col as if statement conditions

Tags: python, pandas

It's such a weird question, I don't even know how to phrase it.

`df` looks like this:

```
col4
['df['col1'] == 10]', ['df['col2'] == 'cat']']
['df['col1'] == 20]', ['df['col3'] == 'some string']']
```

`df1` looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
10      cat     some string
20      dog     some string
```

My goal is to use the elements in `df.col4` as conditions in an if statement against another df (`df1`).

Output for `df1.new_col` I'm aiming for is:

```
col1    col2    col3          new_col
10      cat     some string   yes
20      dog     some string   yes
30      pet     some string   no
```

Comment: May you show us the output of the printed df?

Comment: @RichardKYu the main df shows the exact output - i nested pandas conditions into lists in that column.

Comment: `col4` doesn't make sense, please fix the quotes/double-quotes and print a valid representation of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). It allows you to do something like

```
df1.query("col1 == 10 & col3 == 'some string'")
```

which in this case would yield

```
   col1 col2         col3
0    10  cat  some string
```

and use the number of hits to populate the `new_col` column. But it requires you to reformat your conditions in `df.col4` to something that is compatible with `query()`. Also I don't understand why you would keep those conditions as nested lists in a dataframe column, it looks wildly impractical to me.